# How to translate this pure javascript to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
document.getElementById('logbox').scrollTop = 
document.getElementById('logbox').scrollHeight;
```

I tried `$('#logbox').scrollTop` but there is not this attribute.

How to access DOM attribute through jQuery object?

Comment: I don't think scrollTop and scrollHeight are element attributes

Comment: @balexandre - Not to mention getting involved in answering questions. 469 questions and counting, and no answers.

Comment: Not to mention that downvotes more than upvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
$('#logbox').scrollTop($('#logbox').attr("scrollHeight"));
```

There's a scrollTop function in jquery, but no scrollHeight function. If you pass a value into scrollTop, it serves to set the scroll top offset, so you have to read the scrollHeight attribute of the relevant node using the attr function to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is about as jQuery-like as you can get whilst retaining sanity, as there is no direct support for `scrollHeight` in the library (there is for [`scrollTop`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollTop) though).

```
$('#logbox').each(function() {
    this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
});
```

You should not really be using [`attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) to access `scrollHeight` as other answers have recommended; `attr` is for manipulating *HTML* attributes (href, alt, title, etc.) and `scrollHeight` is a *DOM* attribute.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that attr is for HTML Attributes, not `DOMElement` properties.

Answer (score 2):

$("#logbox").attr( "scrollTop", $("#logbox").attr("scrollHeight") );

For more informations: http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes

Comment: I don't think scrollTop and scrollHeight are element attributes

Comment: Hmm. I actually believe it's a scriptable property, but it's not a valid element attribute. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618%28VS.85%29.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618%28VS.85%29.aspx , https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollTop , https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollHeight etc. 

*scrollTop is part of the MSIE's DHTML object model and is implemented in the Mozilla Gecko engine powering Firefox. scrollTop is not part of any W3C specification or technical recommendation*

Once again, not an element attribute. Definitely

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elem = $('#logbox');
elem.scrollTop(elem.scrollTop());
```

Comment: So DOM attributes become jQuery function calls?

Comment: $("#logbox").scrollHeight is not a function

Comment: No, but `scrollTop` is a getter and setter in jQuery. See http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to make it "more jQuery" - all depends on how often you need to set scrollTop to scrollHeight.

```
// jQuery to get the DOMElement only
var elem = $('#logbox')[0];  // $('#logbox').get(0) works too
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;

// a little more jQuery way - allows you to pass more than one matched element,
// $.fn.each() passes each DOMElement in as the context of `this`
$('.scrollers').each(function() {
  $(this).scrollTop(this.scrollHeight);
});

// even more jQuery way - make your own plugin
$.fn.scrollToBottom = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).scrollTop(this.scrollHeight);
  });
};
$('#logbox').scrollToBottom();
```